# How can i configure kafka acl's configs with spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I want to configure Kafka operation(user create, permission-read/write etc) with Spring boot project. How can I do these operations with spring ?

Comment: You can use Java to run `kafka-acls` shell script

Comment: Well since there's a warning from Stackoverflow about AI answers - ask ChatGPT about it - it gave me a working solution using AdminClient class

Answer (score 0):

You must create an Acl. The link below covers this completely

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authorization.html#authorization-using-acls

Comment: This doesn't answer how to do it from Spring